# Use Module in another page Opencart 2.1

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, opencart2.x, facebook-social-plugins

i am using `Opencart 2.1.x` for website development and i was planning to implement `Social Logins` for Registration process.

I searched on internet to implement for same. The extensions are too much priced , so i decided to develop on my own.

Here is the approach that i followed to get the things work:

**Controller**

```
catalog/controller/facebook/facebook.php
```

**Module**

```
catalog/controller/module/facebook.php
```

**Language File**

```
catalog/language/english/facebook/facebook.php
```

**Template File**

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/facebook.php
```

Contents in template file are as below::

```
<div class="box box-fbconnect">
   <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
     <div class="box-content">
       <a class="box-fbconnect-a" href="<?php echo $facebook_url; ?>">
        <?php echo $facebook_button; ?></a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

As per my understanding , i did place all files correctly. But now i am unsure how to add this `FaceBook Module` in `registration.tpl` file.

Any clues? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a module that you developed. A module's files are present both in catalog, as well as admin. Please refer to this link.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-opencart-module-development--cms-21873

Comment: will you please tell me how can i use facebook.tpl in my register.tpl if i do not consider it as a module

Comment: You might wanna see the chart controller inside dashboard in admin. It is as per your needs. Check admin dashboard controller. It is calling 6 controllers inside it.